# Swift- Using NSNotification to show ads in SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications, skscene

So I have a game in SpriteKit almost fully coded and now I want to ad interstitial ads when the player dies. I believe NSNotifications would be the best way to do it but I am struggling to figure it out.

So I have a UIViewController that is set up to display interstitial ads, and it works, but I am having trouble getting it to display when the user dies.

Here is some code from ViewController that has all the functions to load the ads in it. I believe this is where I'd use addObserver to receive the NSNotification, but I'm not sure.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ADInterstitialAdDelegate {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "showAdSelector", name: "showAnAd", object: nil)
}

func showAdSelector() {
    loadAd() //loads the ad
}
```

Then, here is the code I use in my PlayScene.swift file, which is an SKScene.

```
class PlayScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {


func didBeginContact(contact:SKPhysicsContact) {
    loadAnAd()        
    }

func loadAnAd() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("showAnAd", object: nil)
    }

}
```

When the player dies and initiates the didBeginContact function nothing happens. I'm sure I'm doing something terribly wrong but I have been trying to find an answer to this and watching tutorials for hours but I still can't solve it. I'd be very grateful is someone could help me figure this out or point me in the right direction! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The notification you post `"showAnAd"` and the notification you observe `"ShowAnAd"` are different. They have to exactly match in case. Try

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "showAdSelector", name: "showAnAd", object: nil)
```

and

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("showAnAd", object: nil)
```

Comment: Oops I missed that. But after I fixed it, still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: is the function `showAdSelector` being called? Try putting a println("showAdSelector") inside it.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't get called.

Comment: I updated it but I didn't change much. Only changed the name from "ShowAnAd" to "showAnAd" so it matches.

Comment: did you verify whether `loadAnAd()` is being called?

Comment: Yes, loadAnAd() is being called. It's just the NSNotification part that is not working.

Comment: and `ViewController` contains the `SKView`?

Comment: I'm not sure, how can I check that?

Comment: I have this inside my ViewController if thats what you mean:                                   if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
            let skView = self.view as SKView
            skView.showsFPS = false
            scene.size = skView.bounds.size
            skView.showsNodeCount = false
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }